# Create a column with ranges

Tags: r

My data set is Churn_Modeling: [Churn_Modeling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ov10.png)

I am looking to create a column called c_rating with the following ranges: (<500 -="very poor",  500-600="poor",  601-660="fair", 661-780="good",  and >= 780 – "excellent").

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(readxl)
library(modelr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

```
churn <- read.csv("Churn_Modeling.csv")
```

```
churn$CreditScore <- as.numeric(churn$CreditScore)
class(churn$CreditScore)
```

```
churn$c_rating <- cut(churn$CreditScore, c(-Inf, 500, 600, 601, 660, 661, 780, Inf),
                      levels=c('<=500', '500-600', '601-660', '661-780', '>780'))

churn$c_rating
```

My output is not creating a column c_rating like I thought. Any ideas?

Comment: Libraries do not need to be in quotation marks, `library(tidyverse)` works just fine.

Comment: Your `cut` function has 8 breaks but only 5 labels.  For n breaks you should have n-1 labels.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Deleting my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 1):

use mutate() and case_when().

```
library(tidyverse)

churn <- read.csv("Churn_Modeling.csv")
churn<-churn %>% mutate(c_rating=case_when(CreditScore<500~"very poor", 
                                           CreditScore>=500 & CreditScore<=600~"poor", 
                                           CreditScore>=601 & CreditScore<=660~"fair", 
                                           CreditScore>=661 & CreditScore<=780~"good", 
                                           CreditScore> 780 ~ "excellent"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas Ratto's answer is pretty good. Another way to do it is to first create a user defined function and then use `lapply()`. Here's an example.

```
churn <- read.csv("Churn_Modeling.csv")

churn$CreditScore <- as.numeric(churn$CreditScore)

C_Rating = function(score){
  if (score < 500) 
    rating = "Very Poor"
  else if (score >= 500 & score <= 600)
    rating = "Poor"
  else if (score >= 601 & score <= 660)
    rating = "Fair"
  else if(score >= 661 & score <= 780)
    rating = "Good"
  else
    rating = "Excellent"
  
  return(rating)

}

churn$c_rating = churn$CreditScore %>% lapply(C_Rating)
```